# fscanf is returning segmentation fault while my file pointer is not null

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, scanf

I have been stuck here for an hour. Dont know why i get segmentation fault when file pointer is not null.
anyone plz help me.

```
int load(char* dictionary){
char* word = "";
FILE* fp=fopen(dictionary,"r");
if ( fp!= NULL )
{
    while (fscanf(fp,"%s",word) != EOF) // **getting segmentation fault**
    {
        hash_put(word);
    }
}
else
{
        return false;
}
fclose(fp);
return true;}
```

Comment: It is necessary to secure an area for storing a character string.

Comment: Also, note that you cannot modify the values of a constant string.

Answer (score 1):

What else do you expect? Writing to the read only memory of the string literal is not allowed.

You should allocate some read/write memory... e.g `malloc` (don't forget to `free` at the end), or on the stack char `data[1024];`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not with your file pointer; the problem is your `word` variable.

You've set `word` to point to a *string literal* (`""`), which only has room for the 0 terminator.  Attempting to modify the contents of a string literal invokes undefined behavior.  This, plus the fact that you're going to be storing stuff past the end of the literal, is why your code is crashing.

Arrays do not grow to accomodate additional data. You have to allocate sufficient memory to store your data before you attempt to read it.

```
#define WORD_SIZE ... // large enough to hold the largest word in your file
char word[WORD_SIZE];
...
while ( fgets( word, sizeof word, fp ) )
{
  // do stuff with word
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not try giving `word` some memory to store that data?

i.e. an array - try

```
 char data[100];
```